# How to fix the infinite buffer on WooCommerce checkout for Wordpress

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently experiencing an issue where on the checkout page for Woocommerce the order review section is stuck on an infinite buffer (see below). I have Googled around a lot and tried various things but nothing has worked so far.

[image: Image showing infinite buffer on order_review]

On most of the support threads I've seen, people say they have been able to find what has been causing the issue in the logs or console of Chrome/Firefox however I have gone through these and found nothing at all.

When I delete the `blockUI` div it gets rid of the buffer so that I can place a fake order. Here's the interesting part: It still registers as an order and shows up in the Woocommerce Orders section and I get an email notification but it also displays an error which varies across browsers. On Chrome it displays
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

But on Firefox it displays

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 167 of the JSON data`

Additionally, on IE it says `SyntaxError: Invalid character`

So I would like to know how to solve this issue. Please keep in mind that I have disabled all other plugins and that Woocommerce is the only plugin running and I have even set the theme to the 2015 Wordpress default theme. I have heard that AJAX is the culprit so is there a way to disable AJAX on the checkout of Woocommerce and still have the checkout work? (I have Googled this and haven't found a guide on how to disable AJAX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work this one out myself.

I was having a look through the GET/POST logs and found that Woocommerce had a script called `blockUI` so I simply changed the name of the scripts (it has a minified version too) so that they wouldn't be called.

The scripts can be found at `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/jquery-blockui/`

Once I disabled these, there was no infinite buffer and no error (although I believe that is due to the error suppressing "fix" posted by the Woocommerce author [found here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/24-common-issue-syntaxerror-unexpected-token?replies=1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this
In Config File write the following code:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

For more details you can check the this link :
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/24-common-issue-syntaxerror-unexpected-token?replies=1