# WooCommerce Checkout page reloads automatically and infinitely

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the "Porto" eCommerce theme. Everything else works fine. Even if unregistered/"Not logged in" users go to the Checkout page, they can place orders just fine. Problem arises when users login to their account and try to place an order on the "Checkout" page. The page keeps reloading automatically every 2-3 seconds and it keeps repeating this endlessly!
The theme uses loads of plugins and has heavy ajax functionality. Here is the system status: http://pastebin.com/mjFn39pH

What could the possible reasons for this?

**UPDATE:** WooCommerce 2.5.1 is out in the wild and looks like the problem is 99.99% fixed now! I can't say it's 100% solved because the checkout page still reloads unnecessarily, but luckily just for the first time you go to the checkout page and just once. Of course way better than changing the name of the folder `jquery-blockui`, but still not a fully acceptable solution!

Comment: If the problem does not occur with a default theme, then the issue is with your theme and you should contact the theme author.

Comment: I have this issue even with everything deactivated, but WooCommerce 2.5.0 and Twenty Fifteen.

Comment: Will be hopefully fixed in 2.5.1 https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-checkout-page-constantly-refreshing-on-mobile

Comment: @helgatheviking Thanks for the idea, gotta try it.

Comment: @Adrian Looks like the problem is with WC then. I wonder how did so many people use WooCommerce for so long with that bug alive!!

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** *No need to take the following action anymore to solve the problem as the problem gets solved if you upgrade to WC 2.5.1*

Found a solution!

Just renamed the **jquery-blockui** file located here: `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/jquery-blockui/`

Though I'm not sure if it can cause other problems, but as far as I checked everything is running just fine.

Maybe not directly related, but this post helped a lot: [How to fix the infinite buffer on WooCommerce checkout for Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529918/how-to-fix-the-infinite-buffer-on-woocommerce-checkout-for-wordpress?rq=1)

Comment: Looks like the ultimate solution is to resolve the warning/notices coming from plugins/themes.

Comment: It's just a (partial) workaround. AJAX cart isn't working after removing this.

Comment: @Adrian That's right, the dropdown menus are not working either, but that's just on the checkout page where the ajax cart is the least required/used I believe. Then again, a bug is a bug and needs to be fixed.